# Auto Layout error with tableview cell in swift

Tags: swift, autolayout

I'm using autolayout with UITableViewCell and got following errors.
How can I fix it?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

```
2020-09-15 11:42:13.104796+0900 heart-to-heart[14602:1800620] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022eb890 UIImageView:0x7fdd1f01efc0.height == 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022c7480 V:|-(16)-[UIImageView:0x7fdd1f01efc0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdd1f01eb00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022c74d0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fdd1f01efc0]-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdd1f01eb00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022c1d10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdd1f01eb00.height == 82.3333   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022eb890 UIImageView:0x7fdd1f01efc0.height == 50   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: #Kyle Wang Hi. I'm new to StackOverflow. Thanks for editing :)

Comment: You could change the bottom constraint to >=.

Comment: #Don Wow. It works well. Thank you :) Could you explain how it works?

Comment: You should consider using https://www.wtfautolayout.com/ to help debug what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting the height for the ImageView then no need to set the bottom constraint and even top constraint. Remove both bottom and top constraint and add the constraint to centerY i.e. center vertically the image view to the container.

The reason why you are getting this issue is because it is ambiguous as which constraint to satisfy whether the height constraint of the Image view or top/ bottom constraint.

Comment: If it solved your problem, then you can accept the answer.